# Using SQL to return 6 check box flags into three columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to turn multiple check box results in differnet fileds into seperate columns.

The current case statement below only tracked the lowest score into a a single filed called 'Activities Registered For (1) – (5)'. I would like to convert them into 5 columns 'a-e' where 'a' is always filled with a result, and if two options are checked the results are in 'a' and 'b'. The form can be filled in with up to all selections checked. The else statement appears to be an error, since there are to be at least one of the five boxes checked.

I am new to SQL and I adopted this from someone else, so I am sorry for not showing my previous attempts to resolve my issue.

```
 ,CASE 
WHEN [1524#1] = 'Y' THEN '1'
WHEN [1525#1] = 'Y' THEN '2' 
WHEN [1526#1] = 'Y' THEN '3'
WHEN [1527#1] = 'Y' THEN '4'
WHEN [1528#1] = 'Y' THEN '5'
ELSE ' ' END AS 'Activities Registered For (1) – (5)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a PIVOT but multiple CASEs are just as effective, use about the same amount of code and is easier for beginners to decipher.

```
CASE WHEN [1524#1] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ACTIVITY_1, 
CASE WHEN [1525#1] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ACTIVITY_2, 
CASE WHEN [1526#1] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ACTIVITY_3, 
CASE WHEN [1527#1] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ACTIVITY_4, 
CASE WHEN [1528#1] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ACTIVITY_5
```

I don't think the ELSE is necessarily an error. I often add an ELSE than **shouldn't** be used in case there is unexpected data (no **Y** in any field in your example).

Here's some info on PIVOTs if you want to check it out:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query